# Android Adapter notifyDataSetChanged works only on loading (second adapter)

Tags: java, android

I have little trouble with my adapter. After I add new content to my list and refreshing with `notifyDataSetChanged` the `onClickListener` doesn't work for that new item. After I do click back and go back to the add menu, the item works fine.

So the loading part works perfectly.

The first Adapter with list it do works perfectly. Its pretty much the same code.

In `onCreate` function...

```
Button addContent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addContent_button);
final ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainMenuList);
final boolean deleteMode = false;
String[] liegenSchaften = new String[] {};
final List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(liegenSchaften));
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content);

myList.setAdapter(adapter);

//load the Save Data
Map<String, ?> map = getSaveMap();

//add exists data to list
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    content.add(entry.getValue().toString());
}

// Update adapter, this works fine!
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

addContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        content.add(editedText.getText().toString());
        /* This adapter dont Update the new Content, the item display and is not clickeble */
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        editor.putString(editedText.getText().toString(), editedText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
});

myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        //load the Save Data
        Map<String, ?> map = getSaveMap();

        Object obj = myList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        String value = obj.toString();

        //add exists data to list
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().toString() == value) {
                if(deleteMode) {
                    editor.remove(value);
                    editor.commit();

                    content.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    selectedContent = entry.getValue().toString();
                    addMessage.setText(entry.getValue().toString() + " Wurde gewählt.");
                    addMessage.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I remember getting the same issue. If I recall correct, I sidelined the issue by creating the listener inside the adapter class itself.

Comment: how you mean that? maybe you have little example?

Comment: Here you go for the example of a custom adapter - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37235985/3145960

Comment: thanks for the link, have see it befor. I need to know why this fold is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem:

The query was wrong. Now I have used equals and the `ArrayAdapter` works beautifully!

```
 if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(value))
```